# Как работает рекурсия в консольном калькуляторе?

Tags: java, рекурсия

Не могу понять, правильно ли я понял рекурсию в консольном калькуляторе.

Есть такой код

```
public static int getInt(){
    System.out.println("Введите число:");
    int num;
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        num = scanner.nextInt();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе числа. Попробуйте еще раз.");
        scanner.next();//рекурсия
        num = getInt();
    }
    return num;
}
```

Но если убрать кусок кода  "scanner.next();" то бесконечно будет печатать
"Введите число:"
"Вы допустили ошибку при вводе числа. Попробуйте еще раз."

А если сделать так

```
public static int getInt(){
    System.out.println("Введите число:");
    int num;
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        num = scanner.nextInt();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Вы допустили ошибку при вводе числа. Попробуйте еще раз.");
        String ggg = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ви ввели не число, ви ввели" + " " + ggg);
        num = getInt();
    }
    return num;
```

}

То напечатает то что я ввел. Я правильно понимаю что Scanner уже сохранил то что я ввел первый раз и с ним надо что то сделать, как-то обнулить?

Comment: и при чём тут рекурсия? совершенно непонятный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

`scanner.hasNextInt()` только проверяет, является ли текущее введенное значение целым числом. То есть после этой функции на входе сканера по прежнему введенное значение. Если целое - то идет вызов `scanner.nextInt();` оно считывает число и переводит сканер к вводу следующего значения, если не целое то  иначе в блок `else`. `scanner.next()` это не рекурсия. Это считывание данных сканера до следующего символа разделителя(по умолчанию пробел) и переводит указателя(условно) сканера к следующему вводимому значению. Рекурсия у вас в строке `num = getInt();` (то есть вызов функции самой себя) Логично, если убрать `scanner.next()`, то сканер по прежнему будет иметь на входе ваши первоначально введенные данные и будет бесконечно вызывать `getInt()` с одним и тем-же результатом.

> Я правильно понимаю что Scanner уже сохранил то что я ввел первый раз и с ним надо что то сделать, как-то обнулить?

Примерно так. В ваших примерах `scanner.next()` и `scanner.nextLine()` возвращают введенные значения сканера и переводят его к готовности вводить следующее значение.

Comment: выделите код по правилам, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Условный оператор if выдвигает условие: scanner.hasNextInt() - нужно целое число.
num = scanner.nextInt() - Если вводится целое число то оно присваивается "num" и уходит в команду return num; в методе getInt();.
Команда return num;  отправляет целое число в метод main(), в переменные int num1 = getInt();  и  int num2 = getInt();
Если не целое число введено, то такой ввод идёт в тело else { ...}. И в этом теле
метод scanner.next(); принимает этот ввод и хоронит его, т.е. никуда не отправляет и никому не присваивает.
Следующая команда, рекурсия num = getInt(); отправляет программу в начало своего же метода getInt(); и опять предлагает ввести целое число. Так она, рекурсия работает, пока не введёте целое число и не перепрыгнете else { ...}, рекурсия будет отправлять программу в начало своего же метода. Введёте целое число, перепрыгнете else { ...}, и отправите число в main().